# Where is the information about the allocated memory regions?

Tags: windows, x86, virtual-memory, mmu

I am interested in what address and in what form the information about the allocated regions of virtual memory is stored in the process memory. In other words, where is the information that Mark Russinovich’s utility "vmmap.exe" reads.[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsxUP.jpg)

Comment: I assume it's *not* stored *in* the process's own virtual address space.  It's in the kernel, and you read it (for your own process or for another process) by making a system call.

Answer (score 2):

That data is maintained by the operating system and stored in the system space. The utility in question is calling Windoze API functions like this—

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery

—to retrieve information about the process.